# Specify what fields show when creating/editing a list item

Tags: task-list, list-item, edit-form

When a user opens/edits/creates a list item, how do you specify what fields are shown by default (as opposed to having to click Show More to see)?

In the example image below, the Task Name, Start Date, Due Date, Assigned To, and % Complete fields are shown by default. If you click Show More, there are many other fields that I want to be shown by default without having to click Show More to see.

[image]

Comment: A similar question was asked before. Hope it might help you.  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71565/show-more-by-default

Comment: That's useful information, but it doesn't really help me because I don't want to show all fields by default. I want to be able to pick and choose which fields are shown by default, which fields are shown when you click Show More, and which fields aren't shown at all (i have some calculated columns that I don't want users to see)